# folderBrowserDialog does not work in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

when i click on the button to select a folder using folderBrowserDialog in c#
the dialog is not shown and the result of dialog is set to **Cancel** automatically ..here is the code behind Button_Click :

```
private void glassButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();//here Dialog is not shown and result=Cancel
    if (result==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        backupPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath.ToString();
        if (Directory.Exists(backupPath))
            backupTextBox.Text = backupPath;
        //else MessageBox.Show("path is invalid", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }
}
```

how can i fix it ? 
thanks .

Comment: Is it drag and drop? Or did you create folderBrowserDialog in your own?

Comment: Where is the code created that created the `folderBrowserDialog1`

Comment: and fyi, the line `folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = true;` is set after the dialog closed.

Comment: @MatthewWhited i put the control into the form from toolbox

Answer (score 3):

Add STAThread Attribute to the main method.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ...        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code, it works fine for me.

```
using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         // some code...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You code works correctly.
result is *DialogResult.OK* when you click FolderBrowserDialog "OK Button". if you click "cancel" or "close" button when result value setting is DialogResult.Cancel

Answer (score 0):

from **project properties -> build section -> platform target** , i checked **Prefer 32-bit** checkBox and it solved my problem .

Comment: i think the problem is someways related to the **COM** components , as folderBrowserDialog is a component from COM technology, but i don't know what the problem was with that .